# Cover the n-sphere with sub-hemispherical caps

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, computational-complexity, spherical-geometry, discrete-geometry

Original Question (answered):

Define a cap (x,Phi) to be the set of all points of the sphere that are within an angle Phi of the point x.  $ 0 \le \phi < \frac{\pi}{2} $.  (define the angle between 2 points as the angle between these points considered as vectors)

How many such caps do you need to cover the surface of the n-sphere?

Answer: n+2

Expanded Question:
What if we bound the angle $\phi$ by a smaller constant, i.e. $ 0 \le \phi < \theta < \frac{\pi}{2} $, for some $\theta$?

Comment: The expanded question is googleable as [packing spherical caps](http://www.google.com/search?q=packing+spherical+caps).  (Well, strictly speaking, you want coverings, not packing, but they're closely related problems.)

Answer (score 3):

Take the intersection of $x_0^2+...+x_n^2=n^2+n$ and $x_0+...+x_n=0$.  This is an $n-1$-dimensional surface of an $n$-dimensional sphere.
It contains the points
$(n,-1,-1,-1,...,-1)$, $(-1,n,-1,...,-1)$ and so on.
For any point on the sphere, at least one coordinate is positive, so at least one of the dot products with these points is positive.
So $n+1$ points will do for the $n-1$-dimensional surface.

Comment: I don't think this works... remember that Phi is strictly less than pi/2.

I'm working through this example with the circle.  

We'd have x_0^2+x_1^2 = 2 and x_0 = -x_1, so the solutions are (1,-1) and (-1,1).  But then you miss the points (1,1) and (-1,-1), which are orthogonal to both of these points.

Comment: The circle is $1$-dimensional, so you need $n=2$, so the points in this example are constructed in $\mathbb R^3$, and the circle is realized as the intersection of unit sphere in $\mathbb R^3$ with the plane $x_0+x_1+x_2=0$; note that the indexing starts at $0$ in the initial equations.  (This is a device to make the coordinates easy to describe.)  (Michael is describing a regular $n$-simplex, but really any simplex containing the origin in its interior would do.)

Comment: You have found that the zero-dimensional circle is two points - the boundary of an interval :)

Comment: OK, my mistake.  Thanks much for the quick response!

Comment: I didn't realize this was such an easy question.  I expanded on it so it is considerable more interesting now, maybe.

Comment: I just realized this answer is incomplete; it doesn't prove that you can't use less.